# thread synchronization

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have a process with 2 thread which work like this

Thread1

```
while( true ){
    Time t = getTime();
    Notify/wakeup Thread2 after time 't'

    ....
    ....
}
```

Thread2

```
while( true ) {
     wait for a signal from Thread1

     do some stuff 
}
```

Is there way to achieve this scenario?

If getTime() return 5 unit (absolute time) of time then Thread2 should start executing after 5 unit of time.

PS: I'm using Pthread library, ready to use other library also.

Thanks

Comment: If getTime() returns ms since 1970, what does 'after time t' mean?  Does 'some condition' block?

Comment: `getTime()` return absolute time (may be ms or second) not relative to a particular year

Comment: I have removed `some condition` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `usleep`, conditional variables, and a state variable:

```
pthread_cond_t cond;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int state = 0;

clock_t start, stop;    
while( true ){
    Time t = getTime();
    start = clock();
    // do some action
    stop = clock();

    if((stop - start) < t)
       usleep(t - (stop - start));

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)
    state++;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
}
```

Then in thread 2:

```
while( true ) {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     int st = state;
     while(state == st)
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

     do some stuff 
}
```

Comment: this can be a way to solve but i don't want Thread1 to sleep because it has some other stuff to do.

Comment: So you want something like: thread1 starts, does some action, but if t milliseconds haven't elapsed at the end of the action, wait until t has elapsed and then signal thread2, right? Check if the edit I made is ok.